# Associate InfoPlist.string file with recently created .plist file

Tags: ios, localization, plist

I am working in the localization of an iOS app for english and spanish which also has multiple targets. So for each target i need to create its plist file with its associated plist.strings to support localization in each target.

my question is:

**How do i link a recently created .plist file with a created .string file in each target?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out.

You just have to make sure that the new InfoPlist.strings you create is in the current target.

This seems very straightforward but the issue was that i made a duplicate of my target to make a new one, so in the process the plist of the second one had the Localization keys added because i had this on the first one. Removing the key in the second made the deal and now i can set everything in the new target.